set /p command...Batch file IF-Condition branch is not working well, but CLOSE
I am creating a simple automation command using a batch file on Windows 10, like "Mode Switching batch".
-What I want to do:
If "manual" is written in mode.txt, it asks "change to auto mode? (y/n)". If "y" is entered, it rewrites the mode.txt to Auto and displays "changed to Auto mode". If "n" is entered, it displays "mode is not changed. still "Manual". (The same when contents of mode.txt is "auto".)
-When I tested..
but when I tried it in a test environment this time, even though I entered "y" in "change to Auto mode? (y/n)", mode.txt was not rewritten and "mode is not changed.." was displayed.
I think there is something wrong with the if statement, but I can't find it no matter what.
I have the following command. Can someone please give me some advice on how to make it work according to the above specifications when "y" is selected?
Command:
set "filePath=C:\test\mode.txt"
set /p mode=<%filePath%

echo current mode: %mode%

if /i "%mode%"=="manual" (
 echo change to Auto mode? ^(y/n^)
 set /p choice=
 if /i "%choice%"=="y" (
  echo Auto > %filePath%
  echo Changed to Auto mode.
  pause > to finish this command, please type any key.
  exit /b
 ) else (
  echo mode is not changed, still "Manual".
  echo to finish this command, please type any key.
  pause > null
  exit /b
 )
) else if /i "%mode%"=="Auto" (
 echo Change to Manual mode? ^(y/n^)
 set /p choice=
 if /i "%choice%"=="y" (
  echo Manual > %filePath%
  echo changed to Manual mode.
  echo to finish this command, please type any key.
  pause > null
  exit /b
 ) else (
  echo mode is not changed, still "Auto".
  echo to finish this command, please type any key.
  pause > null
  exit /b
 )
) else (
 echo Error: check the mode.txt
 echo to finish this command, please type any key.
 pause > null
 exit /b
)


Oh - that's line break. Anyhoo, to highlight, just select the code and press {} button. You can also edit the post (edit text under taglist) to supplement the information. Posting as an "answer" is often a noobie faux-pas, and will be routinely deleted as "not an answer". Happens a lot...

As a side note: The device is named NUL, not null.

Please consider choice which is designed for the option-choice task. Use the search facility for [batch-file] choice eg. Gerhard's example or see the documentation - choice /? from the prompt.
Within a parenthesised series of instructions (aka "code block") any %var%, including %errorlevel%, is replaced by the then-current ("parse time") value of that variable when the block syntax is being validated. The syntax if [not] errorlevel n may be used, meaning if the CURRENT errorlevel is [not] "n" OR GREATER THAN "n". Otherwise, delayedexpansion and !var! needs to be used to access the current value of the variable, including magic variables like errorlevel time date cd and others. Stephan's DELAYEDEXPANSION link
